# web interface to pause play stop a running php script

Tags: javascript, php, resume

In short, I have a PHP script that sends bulk SMS to a list of 1 million numbers, I pass the parameters with HTML form and action = sendsms.php

How can I customize this simple solution by adding a Resume, Pause, Stop button?

In better words, any references that could help?

Comment: You can't really stop a PHP script mid way as there is no way to communicate to it.  I would suggest using a queuing system like RabbitMQ where each message is a email to send.  Then you can code in a locking mechanism to check between jobs (Emails) but it's not trivial.

Comment: Essentially php is synchronous by default, or Blocking as it were. So it cannot Listen to commands while executing them.  You may do some asynchronous things with a socket server, but again it's not trivial. I imagine you are looping though an array or something, and in simple terms there is no way to say to PHP to stop.

Comment: The other option is to create a DB table to fill with emails then consume them as the script runs. Have a cron job that runs every minute and pulls a number of emails/sends then/ deletes the record. then you can tell the cron job that if a certain file exists to not pull the emails.  Then you create the file with a pause button, that is the simplest way I can think of.

Comment: The cron job is somewhat prone to race conditions, where cron will run again before the previous instance finished.  So you could have a situation where it could send more then one email if it's not timed correctly.  It's easier then say a queuing system, but less robust.  I do a lot of this stuff, but none of it is really trivial to setup.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: Yea I wish I could be more help, it's just not something PHP is designed to do out of the box.  It can of course do it, but it's not an easy thing to setup.

Comment: but what I am looking for is a way to provide some other simple users to access a web page and bulk SMS as a broadcast, so  I need to provide an interface to enable them to pause and stop sending if something goes south

Comment: I am not saying your answer wasn't helpful, it just means I need to develop this in some other language

Comment: See simple on the front end has nothing to do with the back end. You can have a very complex backend system but a simple front end system.  I really think RabbitMq would be a huge benefit to something like this.  Because you can cancel listening to queues which would have the effect of pausing them.

Comment: None of the languages really support this it's more of an architecture problem.  I cant say I know .net or Java at the same level I know PHP, but you basically need a way to tell them to stop so they need to be checking for a trigger. I don't think they really have 2-way communication by default.

Comment: https://www.rabbitmq.com/  Just for reference.  And https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html

Comment: OK, can I use rabbitmq to trigger kannel url ? or it is totally a different way to send SMS?

Comment: Rabbit is a message system. You put text in (publish) then you have a worker in the background that consumes.  The worker can do anything PHP can do.  But it lets you handle 1 message at a time.  So it gives you a way to check for a lock file in-beteween messages.  JSON is a normal format for a message.

Comment: You don't have to use something like Rabbit, but this question is to much for a simple Q&A on SO.